# Is there an algorithm to generate size $n$ mutually orthogonal latin squares for $n \neq 2, 6$?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, latin-square

Is there an algorithm to generate size $n$ mutually orthogonal latin squares for $n \neq 2, 6$?

For reference, I've been scanning several texts on combinatorics (Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A: Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1" and Lint's "A course in Combinatorics") to find such an algorithm.

I've already read this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624841/algorithms-for-mutually-orthogonal-latin-squares-a-correct-one), but it doesn't seem super helpful to my case.

Comment: Your phrase "it doesn't seem super helpful to my case" is itself unhelpful.  Please share with Readers exactly what your case is.  The Answers to that previous post and the book references (Knuth, Wilson and van Lint) are excellent introductions.  To dig more deeply into a specific problem about MOLS (mutually orthogonal latin squares) would justify a more articulate post on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give an explicit construction of a pair of orthogonal Latin squares of order $n$ as long as $n>1$ and $n$ is not of the form $4k+2$ for some integer $k$. In this last case, I can at least give a citation.

First, assume $n$ is a prime power. Let $(\newcommand{\F}{\Bbb F}\F,\oplus,\otimes)$ be a finite field with $|F|=n$. We will think of the elements of $\F$ as the first $N$ nonnegative integers $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ for convenience, such that $0$ is the additive identity and $1$ is the multiplicative identity. The operations $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ are *not* addition and multiplication modulo $n$ (except when $n$ is prime).

For each $k\in \F^\times$, we define an $n\times n$ Latin square $M^k$ as follows:
$$
M^k_{i,j}=k\otimes i\oplus j\qquad i,j\in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}
$$
Note that I am using zero-indexing to describe the entries of $M^k$.

It is then easy to use the properties of finite fields to show that $\{M^1,M^2,\dots,M^{n-1}\}$ is a MOLS.

What about when $n$ is not a prime power? For this, the following "product" construction of Latin squares is useful. Let $L$ be a Latin square of order $\ell$, and $M$ be a Latin square of order $m$. For convenience, assume that the row indices, column indices, and labels for $L$ (resp. $M$) take values in $\{0,1\dots,\ell-1\}$ (resp. $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$). Then the product Latin square $L\times M$ is defined to be
$$
(L\times M)(i,j)=\ell\cdot M(i\,\%\, m,j \,\%\, m)+L(\lfloor i/m\rfloor,\lfloor j/m\rfloor)
$$
Here, $a\,\%\,b$ refers to the remainder of $a$ when divided by $b$, which is always in $\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}$.

You can then show that if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are orthogonal Latin squares of order $a$, and $B_1$ and $B_2$ are orthogonal Latin squares of order $b$, then $A_1\times B_1$ is orthogonal to $A_2\times B_2$. Using this construction, along with the existence of orthogonal Latin squares for all prime powers except for $2^1$, you can prove that two orthogonal Latin squares exist for all $n$, *except* when $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$. To do this, factorize $n$ into prime powers, find an orthogonal pair of each prime power order, then combine them together with the product. When $n=4k+2$, this method fails since there do not exist orthogonal squares of order $2$.

For the exception case $n=4k+2$, there is a construction, but it is much more complicated. A complete proof is given in section 4.4 of *Combinatorial Designs and Tournaments*, by Ian Anderson, but it is too involved for me to reproduce here.